# User Authentication in password grace period

Tags: php, apache, windows-authentication

PHP Version 5.3.10

I'm using Apache on a Windows network and when I call $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] it works fine until the user enters the password expiry grace period (you have x days until your password expires) when all they see is this message:

> **Authorization Required** The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the
>   wrong credentials (eg bad password), or your browser doesn’t
>   understand how to supply the credentials required.

Is there any way of catching this and presenting a more helpful message to the user?

**Update**
Thanks Fred for the useful information. I added the following line to .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 401     /401.php
```

and added 401.php to the same folder as .htaccess and I immediately got the following error when trying to access the site:

> Authorization Required This server could not verify that you are
>   authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the
>   wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't
>   understand how to supply the credentials required.
>
> Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

As a test I also added

```
ErrorDocument 404     /404.php
```

and was correctly given the alternative page not found message.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Then to catch the error, you would just use a function to write to file". Do you have an example? Following is the code I use to get the user's username:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
$domainarray = explode("\\",$domain);
$username = strtolower ($domainarray[1]);
```

Comment: I think that's a **401** default document message. You could put something to the affect of `ErrorDocument 401 /path_to/401.php` in your `.htaccess`, then just make up a file called `401.php` and fancy it up from there. Then to catch the error, you would just use a function to write to file.

Comment: If my comment above solved your problem, then I will make it as an answer, so your question can be closed and **marked as solved**.

Comment: @Fred Reading up on ErrorDocument. Will edit my original question.

Comment: In your edited question, you wrote "I'm not sure what you mean by Then to catch the error...", this was in response to `"Is there any way of catching this..."`. I thought you meant that, you wanted to "log" the error. Now, I think there may be a conflict happening, the server says a 401 (`Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered...`). I think this one may be **"out of my league"** as it were. I suggest you change your question's title to better reflect the issue. Sorry I couldn't be of more help Dion, that's the best I could think of, with the knowledge I have.

Comment: It seems like the 401 is bouncing back to 404 and vice-versa. You may have to set up an `if/else` statement. I just can't wrap my head around it right now.

Comment: **Potential stupid question**: You did created the file `401.php` right?

Comment: Yeah I did. And I can access 401.php directly from the browser but ErrorDocument doesn't seem to be able to access it. I think I've 'solved' it by using **ErrorDocument 401 "Reset your password!"** instead of 401.php. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hm.. bizarre that it didn't work using the `401.php` file, real bizarre. Oh well, I'm glad you found a solution, and you're quite welcome.